# How to manually purge the requirejs cache

Tags: unit-testing, requirejs, client-side

I am jasmine unit testing a module with requirejs and [using the requirejs map configuration](http://fragphace.pl/blog/2013-03-13-Mocking-requirejs-dependencies) to provide a mocked dependency. However, this works well only on the first test run, afterwards the module is already loaded and cached versions are retrieved, so additional tests end up not loading their mocks but returning the mock of the first test.

So suppose I have this

```
define 'directory', ['dataService'], (ds) ->
  ds.doStuff()

configureStub = (name, fn) ->
  define name, fn
  require.config
    map:
      directory:
        dataService: name

describe 'test fixture 1', ->
  beforeEach ->
    configureStub 'mockDataService1', -> doStuff: -> console.log "doing things"
  it "uses the first mock service" -> ...

describe 'test fixture 2', ->
  beforeEach ->
    configureStub 'mockDataService2', -> doStuff: -> console.log "doing other things"
  it "uses the second mock service" -> ...
```

Because both `directory` and `dataService` are cached and the page is not refreshed between tests, `mockDataService2` will never actually be loaded, it will always be `mockDataService1`!

Is there a way to manually purge `directory` and `dataService` from requirejs' cache in my test setup?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this is still a valid question that merits an answer but for people in the *exact* same situation as me, I managed to solve the problem with a combination of squire.js and jasmine.ajax.